# passing data from an Activity to another Activity Android

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my class:

```
public class Asset extends  BaseModel implements Serializable{...}
```

and on an Activity I have this:

```
private void openAssignAssetIntent(String actionType){
    Intent assignAssetIntent = new Intent(this,AssignAssetActivity.class);
    assignAssetIntent.putExtra("currentAsset",currentAsset);
    startActivity(assignAssetIntent);
}
```

and I am trying to get this value("currentAsset") from another Activity like this:

```
Asset asst = (Asset) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("currentAsset");
```

But I am getting this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: give full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: are you passing object from one activity to other ?

Comment: You should use Parcelable instead of Serializable in Android when trying to send data using Intent. (It's more Android way)

Comment: @hardartcore, why? `Serializable` is not proxibited, and should work too. Parcellable is just and Android faster serialization implementation

Comment: @VladMatvienko exactly! It's more faster and build for Android, not that you can't use Serializable.

Comment: Check your logcat again.There will be a line like this  `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:`:"your package name.someclass" . Check if that is Serilizable. Or give full stacktrace.

Comment: Can you put here full code for Asset class?

Comment: @hardartcore, but this does not mean that everybody **should** use Parcelable instead of `Serializable`. I sometimes have situation where I'm not going to implement Parcelable  to quickly serialize something that doesn't need high performance. I won't use Parcelable, but will use Serializable

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bundle` instead:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("currentAsset", currentAsset);
Intent assignAssetIntent = new Intent(this,AssignAssetActivity.class);
assignAssetIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(assignAssetIntent);
```

and then retrieve it like

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

Asset asset = (Asset) bundle.getSerializable("currentAsset");
```

hope this helps

Comment: @VladMatvienko no, he is not using a Bundle, please consider reading again the code

Comment: @VladMatvienko and he is not using putSerializable also

Comment: @VladMatvienko no problem ;)